# Prove that norm of Yosida approximations blows up

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I need an help with the following exercise about Yosida approximations. Let's fix the notation: let $A$ be an unbounded linear operator define on a  dense domain $D(A)\subset X$ of a Banach space $X$.

Define the resolvents $J_n:=(I-\frac{1}{n}A)^{-1}$ and the Yosida approximations $A_n:=n(J_n-I)$.

We have already proved that, if $x\in D(A)$, $||A_n x||\to ||A x||$ as $n\to \infty.$ Our aim is to prove that, if $x\notin D(A)$ then the sequence $\{||A_nx||\}$ is increasing and unbounded, i.e. $||A_nx||\to \infty$.

How can we prove it? We have tried to prove it directly by definition of $A_n$, but we got stuck. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Something is amiss here: perhaps $A$ should be assumed closed. Otherwise, nothing prevents $A$ from having a bounded extension to the span of $D(A)\cup \{x\}$.

Comment: I don't know actually, but it is really probable since my professor tends to forget important hypothesis.